# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function sp_friend has too many arguments specified.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to make a ForgotPassword button, but it shows me this error. Here is the code for ForgotPassword.aspx.cs:

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string question;
        string ans;
        if (ddlquestions.SelectedItem.Text == "other")
        {
            question = txtothers.Text;
        }
        else
        {
            question = ddlquestions.SelectedItem.Text;
        }

        ans = txtsecurityans.Text;
        string uid = txtuser.Text;
        dr = a.registration(3, uid, "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", question, ans, "", 0, false);
        if (dr.Read())
        {
            string encrypted = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
            try
            {
                System.Text.UTF8Encoding encoder = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();
                System.Text.Decoder utf8Decode = encoder.GetDecoder();
                byte[] todecode_byte = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted);
                int charCount = utf8Decode.GetCharCount(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length);
                char[] decoded_char = new char[charCount];
                utf8Decode.GetChars(todecode_byte, 0, todecode_byte.Length, decoded_char, 0);
                string result = new String(decoded_char);
                MailMessage mailMsg = new MailMessage();
                mailMsg.From = new MailAddress("testvnr@gmail.com");
                mailMsg.To.Add(dr.GetValue(1).ToString());
                mailMsg.Subject = "Your Password";
                mailMsg.Body = "Your password for the account is: " + result;
                mailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
                SmtpClient c = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("testvnr@gmail.com", "testaccount123");
                c.Credentials = cred;
                c.EnableSsl = true;
                try
                {
                    c.Send(mailMsg);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Response.Write(ex.Message);
            }

        }
```

And here is the registration function:

```
   public SqlDataReader registration(int flag, string uid, string fname, string lname, string email, string address, string city, string country, string phonenumber, string gender, string dob, string photo, string secques, string secans, string pswd, int utype, bool status)
    {
        con.sqlconnection();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_login", con.myConnection);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", flag);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uid", uid);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", fname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", lname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country", country);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phonenumber", phonenumber);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", gender);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", (dob));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@photo", photo);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secques", secques);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secans", secans);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pswd", pswd);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@utype", utype);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        return rd;
    }
```

I have connected with sp_login stored procedure, I do not know why it keeps showing me this error, with sp_friend stored procedure. Can sb help me? Where else should I look?

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Learn to use a debugger - run your code in debug mode and find the statement that throws the error.

Comment: Side note: ["AddWithValue is Evil"](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Yes I understand the error, but I am asking for the reason why the error shows me the name of another procedure while in method registration I have used another stored procedure of mine.

Comment: WEll for one - if `flag == 0` - you do **not** assign anything to `rd`, but you still return it from the method - so what exactly are you getting back from that method then ????

Comment: flag==0 is the check for userid, in my stored procedure, but I do not think this is the problem, because here the flag ==3